# How to generate SAS token for secure connection to Azure IOT hub

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub

I need to programmatically generate the `SAS` token required for the connection to `Azure` IoT hub. For this I am following this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token).

In the below C# code:

```
private static string createToken(string resourceUri, string keyName, string key)
{
    TimeSpan sinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    var week = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
    var expiry = Convert.ToString((int)sinceEpoch.TotalSeconds + week);
    string stringToSign = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri) + "\n" + expiry;
    HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
    var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
    var sasToken = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signature), expiry, keyName);
    return sasToken;
}
```

we need to input `resourceUri` which I believe is `<somename>.azure-devices.net`, keyname is the policyname and key can be used as primary or secondary key.

After using the above parameters and generating the SAS token, I am still facing authorization issue and my device is showing as disconnected in device explorer. Can anyone please tell me what I am using wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: try to use the following string formatting: "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}" for device-facing endpoint.

Comment: the key is the primary/secondary key of the specific device, so each device has own authentication sas token.

Comment: @RomanKiss Sorry I didnt get you. Can you answer it and explain a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following changes:

```
    private static string createToken(string resourceUri, string key, string keyName = null)
    {
        TimeSpan sinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        var week = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
        var expiry = Convert.ToString((int)sinceEpoch.TotalSeconds + week);
        string stringToSign = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri) + "\n" + expiry;
        HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
        var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));

        var sasToken = keyName == null ?
            String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signature), expiry) :
            String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signature), expiry, keyName);

        return sasToken;
```

}

usage:

```
var deviceSasToken = MyHelper.createToken("{somename}.azure-devices.net/devices/myDeviceId", devicePrimaryKey);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still didnt get it. Why are you not using keyname. I tried the above code and still facing the authorization issue.

Comment: Sorry, I have forget to add the deviceId in the resourceUri argument, see my updated usage.

Comment: try to compare (formatting) your sastoken with a token generated by device explorer (ManagementTab). Also, for test purpose, try to use a sastoken generated by device explorer.

Comment: I just tested the above generated sastoken with the HTTP and MQTT protocol for sending a D2C message. Which device protocol are you using? Note, that the http protocol is a connectionless, so you will not see a status connected.

Comment: I have a `raspberry pi` where I am using mqtt broker. In the mqtt configuration file I am using SAS token to connect to iot hub. What do you mean when you say you will not see status connected. I also didnt get you by HTTP

Comment: If we are not able to see the correct status of the device in device explorer, then what is its use.?

Comment: I have said, for connection-less protocol such as a HTTP we will not see a status connected. In the opposite, when the device protocol is a connection oriented such as MQTT and AMQP, we can see the status connected/disconnected. I do recommend to read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security and using the MQTT protocol direct  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly

Comment: Thanks for the link you shared, I tried the the C# code on that link to generate sas and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If the key you entered is your device's primary key, then in the code snippet above:

```
HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
```

must be:

```
HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(key));
```

Then it works for me.